# using histogram2d with categorical dimension

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, histogram

This is a scatterplot of [business addresses in Melbourne](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Economy/Business-establishments-with-trading-name-and-indu/bs7n-5veh) by ANZSIC division names.

```
sns.pairplot(x_vars=["x coordinate"]
             , y_vars=["y coordinate"]
             , data=d
             , hue="div_name"
             , size=5
             , aspect=1.7
             , kind='scatter'
             , plot_kws={'alpha':0.3, 's':3})
```

[image: Melbourne businesses]

I would like to use a [2dhistogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439961/efficiently-create-a-density-plot-for-high-density-regions-points-for-sparse-re) to plot the relative density of each business count per pixel. I also would like to be able to make the biggest count to surface, revealing the colour that was assigned by the legend.

`scipy.histogram2d` and `plt.imshow` are able to plot [one histogram at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439961/efficiently-create-a-density-plot-for-high-density-regions-points-for-sparse-re), but I'm having trouble both normalising the very tall centres (small towns disappear when compared to Melbourne) and properly displaying many categories at the same time.

Yes, tall order. Hopefully someone would help me with some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It will be slow for big datasets, but for the time being I think `seaborn`'s `kdeplot` is covering my back... :)

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

extent = (b['x coordinate'].min(), b['x coordinate'].max(), b['y coordinate'].min(), b['y coordinate'].max())

ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1],
                projection=ccrs.LambertCylindrical())
ax.set_extent(extent, ccrs.LambertCylindrical())

cols = ['x coordinate','y coordinate', 'div_name','div_code']
dd = d[cols]
dd.columns = ['long','lat', 'div_name','div_code']
educ = dd.loc[dd.div_code == 'P']
retail = dd.loc[dd.div_code == 'G']
ax = sns.kdeplot(educ.long, educ.lat,
                cmap="Reds", n_levels=5, shade=False, shade_lowest=False, plot_kws={'alpha':0.3}, ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(retail.long, retail.lat,
                cmap="Blues", n_levels=5, shade=False, shade_lowest=False, plot_kws={'alpha':0.3}, ax=ax)

base.plot(linewidth=0
        ,color='gray'
        ,alpha=.1
        ,ax=ax)
```

[image]